# Can a regular language be defined using recursive regular expressions?

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions, finite-state-machine

My problem is essentially that I can't find anything that explicitly prohibits or allows such definitions. To illustrate with an example:

Our teacher challenged us to create a definition for a language using only regular expressions (namely, using only Kleene closure, positive closure, union, and concatenation). The alphabet we are using is $\{0,1\}$, and the language we are to define is the language of all strings whose lengths are multiples of $4$, with no consecutive $1$'s.

If I understand correctly, it's not difficult to show that this is a regular language. From the Wikipedia article on [regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Equivalent_formalisms), it's not too difficult to build a [deterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) that accepts this language.

My question, however, is whether or not I have formally defined this language correctly. The best answer I have come up with (so far) is the following recursive definition (where the target language is $A$):
$$\begin{align*}
A &= B \cup \{1010, 1000\}A \cup \{1001\}B\\
B &= \{\lambda\} \cup \{0000, 0010, 0100\}A \cup \{0001, 0101\}B
\end{align*}$$

where $\lambda$ is the empty string, $\cup$ is union, and $B$ is another language I created to help define $A$. I'm reasonably confident that this a correct definition, though I can explain my reasoning further if anyone wants. However, I'm not sure it's a "good" definition, so if anyone could clarify that, it would be appreciated.

Edit: As per comment request, I've created an FSM that recognizes this language. I'm not sure that it can be represented by a deterministic finite automaton (which I only learned about in googling for this question), but I think it is. Also, I've never really used Latex, so I'm just using a code block.

Anyways, the FSM:

```
      |    v    |   w   |
State |  0 |  1 | 0 | 1 |
      |    |    |   |   |
   s0 | s1 | s5 | 0 | 0 |
   s1 | s2 | s6 | 0 | 0 |
   s2 | s3 | s7 | 0 | 0 |
   s3 | s0 | s4 | 1 | 1 |
   s4 | s1 | s8 | 0 | 0 |
   s5 | s2 | s8 | 0 | 0 |
   s6 | s3 | s8 | 0 | 0 |
   s7 | s0 | s8 | 1 | 0 |
   s8 | s8 | s8 | 0 | 0 |
```

Here's how it works: It starts at s0. s0 and s4 indicate that the length is a multiple of 4, s1 and s5 indicate that the length is 1 greater than a multiple of 4, etc. s0-s3 indicate that the last character is a 0, while s4-s7 indicate that it is a 1. s8 is a reject- and sink-state that is reached iff there are two 1's in a row. A 1 is output each time s0 or s4 are reached, which indicates the length is a multiple of 4 and there have been no consecutive 1's.

I honestly have no idea how to create a regular expression using an FSM, but if there is a way to do that, it would probably answer my question.

Comment: I've edited your maths into MathJax (see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/10513) for a tutorial). I don't think anything got lost when I did this, but please check :-).

Also, I'm not convinced by your construction. For it to be a recursive definition you need to "initialise" $A$ and $B$ somehow. So $A_0$ is something, $B_0$ is something else, and then $A_{n+1}=\ldots$ and $B_{n+1}=\ldots$. You haven't done this.

Comment: @user1729 Thanks for the editing help! That looks correct.
As for recursion, the "base case" could be considered λ, and then essentially any number prefixes can be added. Give me a couple minutes, and I'll work on changing my definition to more explicitly show that.

Comment: OK, but I don't think this is the way to do this problem. Have you tried finding an automata which will accept this language? From there it is pretty straight forward to find the definition you want.

Comment: I have found an automata, but I'm not sure how I could represent it here, nor how to work backwards to an expression. Also, when trying to redefine the my solution, I ran into the issue that I was not following the limits of the problem--I was not limiting myself to Kleene closure, positive closure, union, and concatenation, but rather using a "such that" (e.g., {w | w has length 4}, which is not permitted here.
Edit: As soon as I posted this, I realized I could just put in the table of v's and w's. Should I edit such a table into the question itself? I'm not too familiar with protocol here.

Comment: Sure, edit it in (no one has answered yet so its no problem). Pictures are tricky to draw here, but if you want you could upload a photo. I don't think working backwards to the expression is not too hard, but I'm rusty so I may be wrong here :-)

Comment: I think the FSM I created can be easily understood using only the table for the v and w functions. However, I'm not sure how I could insert a table here. Is there any way to do that? If not, I'll just clean up my work and upload a photo.

Comment: To create tables, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29979/10513 (or search for "table" in the link I gave at the start).

Comment: I've honestly never really used Latex before, and I've got to go soon, so I just used a code block. However, it should get the point across.